# How do post a Photo to Facebook when a post is published?

Tags: plugins, facebook

I have a wordpress site. It is now using the [official Facebook plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/). When a new post is published, an action will be posted to Facebook. The posted message contains a small thumbnail , post title and some description.

But I want to change this approach. I found [Posterous](http://posterous.com) allow user post a photo to Facebook when a post is published.

Does anyone know any Wordpress plugin which can post a photo to Facebook when publishing?

Thanks all. :)